# Check if "cin" is a string

Tags: c++, string, input, int, cin

I have a simple little script I am coding, and I am trying to not allow people to enter a string, or if they do make it revert to the beginning of the function again. Here's the input code I have:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Input your first number" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Input your second number" << endl;
    cin >> b;
}
```

The rest of the code beyond this part works just fine for what's going on, although if a string is entered here it obviously doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post working code - `a` and `b` aren't declared here.

Comment: What are the types of `a` and `b` respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this post useful,

[How to check if input is numeric in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655142/how-to-check-if-input-is-numeric-in-c)

Basically you can check the input, whether it is numeric value or not. After checking whether the given input is numbers, then you can add a while loop in main to ask user to repeat if input is not a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

Every input is a string. If you want to know if a entered string can convert to a number, you have to read in a string and try to convert it yourself (eg with [strol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)).

An alternative would be to check if the reading from cin failed, but personally i don't like it because cin.fail() covers more error situations than just a failed type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library function may help,you can check it after input:

```
int isdigit(char c);
```

Tips:
1.You should include such files :

```
# include <ctype.h>
```

2.If c in 0 ~ 9 ,return 1 ; else return 0.