# try catch repeating loop

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

Hey all this is my code

```
void Student::studentMenu() {
    int choiceInput;
    const string ErrorMsg;
    cout << "-------------Student Menu--------------" << endl;
    cout << "(1)Start Quiz" << endl;
    cout << "(2)View History Score Table" << endl;
    cout << "(0)Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Option: " << endl;
    try {
        cin >> choiceInput;

        if (choiceInput < 0 || choiceInput>2 || !cin)
        {
            throw (ErrorMsg);
        }

        while (choiceInput != 0) {
            switch (choiceInput) {
            case 1:
                generateQuiz();
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 0:
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (string msg)
    {
        cout << "Please only enter valid integer from 0-3" << endl;
        Student::studentMenu();
    }
}
```

Basically it checks the user input and throw an exception if its a non integer larger than 3. After displaying the error message, it should redirect back to the student menu() page. The output is intended when i enter an integer like 5 but when i enter a char 'f' it keeps looping the error message

Please help me thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cin >> choiceInput;
```

What happens when the input is not a parsable integer, cin does not automatically skip over it. That means that you get stuck on that value: You try to read it, it fails, you go one iteration deeper, you try to read it, it fails, etc. To fix this, you should [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the wrong characters in case reading fails (e.g. `!cin` returns true). Typically, this would look something like this:

```
if (!cin) {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
} //proceed
```

(`cin.clear()` is required to clear the `failbit`, so that `!cin` becomes false again)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initilize you `choiceInput` variable with an invalid value:

```
int choiceInput = -1;
```

And in you catch use `cout.flush()` to be sure that you clean the buffers before calling to `studentMenu()`:

```
  catch (string msg)
  {
    cout << "Please only enter valid integer from 0-3: " << choiceInput << endl;
    cout.flush();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

choiceInput is an integer and the ascii value of 'f' is 102 which is > 2. I would recommend you should add some more checks on choiceInput to make sure it is an integer and not a character.

See

[How to check if input is numeric in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655142/how-to-check-if-input-is-numeric-in-c)

Comment: since the value is 102 it still falls outside the invalid input like 10 but why is it looping? it does not happen to 10 though..

and yep i have to use try and exception for this