# Fixing infinite loop

Tags: c++

I have a code that takes 2 numbers from user and check if the input is equal or more than 0 and also checks if the input is numeric.

Everything is fine until I test the code with a non numeric value like "Hi".

By doing this the program goes into an infinite loop.

I want the code request another input if the user entered bad input but it goes into a nonstop loop.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class Exp:public runtime_error
    {
        public:
            Exp(): runtime_error("input must be a numeric value equal or more than 0!\n")
            {
            }
    };

class GradeBook
{
    private:
        float number1,number2;
    public:
        GradeBook(float n1, float n2) : number1(n1), number2(n2)
        {
        }
        void setnumber1(float num1, int re1)
        {
            if(num1 >= 0 && re1)
                number1 = num1;
            else
                throw (Exp());
        }
        float getnumber1()
        {
            return number1;
        }
        void setnumber2(float num2, int re2)
        {
            if(num2 >= 0 && re2)
                number2 = num2;
            else
                throw (Exp());
        }
        float getnumber2()
        {
            return number2;
        }
};

int main()
{
    int result1, result2;
    float num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
    GradeBook myGradeBook(0, 0);

    reNum1:
    printf("Please enter number 1:\n");
    result1 = scanf("%f", &num1);
    try{
        myGradeBook.setnumber1(num1, result1);
    }
    catch(Exp exp)
    {
        cout<<exp.what();
        goto reNum1;
    }

    reNum2:
    printf("Please enter number 2:\n");
    result2 = scanf("%f", &num2);
    try{
        myGradeBook.setnumber2(num2, result2);
    }
    catch(Exp exp)
    {
        cout<<exp.what();
        goto reNum2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if input is numeric in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655142/how-to-check-if-input-is-numeric-in-c)

Comment: Unrelated, but please avoid labels and `goto`, especially if all you use it for is a simple loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem happens because of `scanf` behaviour. When calling `scanf("%f")` it will try to read a float from `stdin`. When user enters `Hi`, there is no float to read so `scanf` will read nothing and return `0`(the number of format specifiers filled with data read from `stdin`). The issue is that the input still has unread string `Hi` pending, so the next call to `scanf("%f")`, will repeat exactly the same operation.
What you need to do is to "clear" `stdin`, so that user can enter new input. This may be done ie. by calling `getline` on failure:

```
    try{
        myGradeBook.setnumber1(num1, result1);
    }
    catch(Exp exp)
    {
        string tmp;
        getline(cin, tmp);
        cout<<exp.what();
        goto reNum1;
    }
```

Please note, that mixing C-style IO(scanf/printf) and C++ style IO(cout/cin) may have a performance penalty.