# If i want to give any input to my function using cout... how can I give

Tags: c++

```
int do_something(int num)
{
    //stuff happens.
}

do_something(5)
```

Here we have given the input directly to the parameter, but if I want to give input to this using cout...

Like It asks me to give input and it directly store in the (int num)....
How can I give... Please suggest me

Comment: How do you expect to get _input_ from `cout`?

Comment: `std::cout << "Give value for num: "; int num; std::cin >> num; do_something(num);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cout` is an output stream. It is not to take input from. You can use `cin` (which is an inputs stream) to take the input and then pass it to your function.

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
do_something(n);
```

Comment: @AashishJha give it and upvote and accept if you are satisfied with the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The `cout` object in C++ is an object of class `ostream`. It is used to display the output to the standard output device i.e. monitor. It is associated with the standard C output stream `stdout`.

Hence, you can't use `cout` to accept input values. Rather, the possible way is just `cin` simply.

Consider the example:

```
int do_something(int num) {
    .
    .
}

int param, result;

std::cout << "Enter something: ";
std::cin >> param;

result = do_something(param); // return type is integer
```

This is the right method.

Comment: thankyou somuch I m also thinking like this...but had a little bit confussion

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
int x;
std::cin >> x;
do_something(x);
```

Very simply that would work. This pulls a value from `std::cin` and puts it into the variable `x`.

There is a problem with this, the user can put whatever value they want into this. If you expect that the input will ALWAYS be an `int` don't worry.
Likely you'll need to look into verifying inputs. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655142/how-to-check-if-input-is-numeric-in-c) is a SO question about that topic.