# How to add a loop to this program to ensure user enters positive number, if negative make them retype it?

Tags: c++

How can I make sure the user enters a positive number, and if its negative give them an error and make them retype it?

```
int main()
{
    float sq, n;
    cout << "Enter any number:";
    cin >> n;
    sq = sqrt(n);
    cout << "Square root of " << n << " is " << sq;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A while loop to check it. If negative, loop again

Comment: Are you asking how loops work? What kind of loop to use?  Where to put it?  What the condition should be?  Have you thought about what part of your code should repeat?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if input is numeric in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655142/how-to-check-if-input-is-numeric-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily with a do-while loop:

```cpp
int num = 0;
do {
    std::cin >> num;
} while (num < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

here, you can use **while loop** and **if-else** statement within **while loop**.

```
int main()
{
    float sq;
    int n;
    
    cout << "Enter any number:\n";
    while (cin >> n) {
    
      if (n < 0)
        cout << "enter a positive number\n";
      
      else {
      sq = sqrt(n);
      cout << "Square root of " << n << " is " << sq << '\n';
      cout << "Enter any number: \n";
      } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```